# how to add DKIM in parallels plesk panel 11 and how to create DKIM records...?

Tags: panel, plesk, records, dkim

How to add DKIM in parallels plesk panel 11 and how to create DKIM records...?

Answer (score 1):

I did ask in parallels forum the same question and here they replay.

My question:

Parallels Plesk Panel 11.x for Windows

I've enabled the DomainKeys-Signature in my server.

Now I want to enable DKIM, how?

==================================================

Summary of Results

==================================================

SPF check: pass

DomainKeys check: pass

**DKIM check: neutral**

Sender-ID check: pass

SpamAssassin check: ham

================================================== ========

**their response**

There is no DKIM automation in Plesk 11.

In order to use DKIM you should:

1) manually add proper TXT records in mail domain

2) enable DKIM in your mail server software

reference: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?p=678592

Answer (score 0):

dkim isnt supported by plesk. domain keys are but they are different. to enable domain keys just type domain keys in the plesk help sections search, will show you step by step.